# Why is Action Mailer redirecting outgoing mail to 'mydomain'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

My Rails app lives on a VPS and sends outgoing mail through an external SMTP server `mail.mydomain`. This has worked for several years, but recently I rebuilt the server to update its infrastructure, which involved moving the VPS to a new IP address. I updated the Address record for `mydomain` to point to the new IP. The MX record points to `mail.mydomain` which is provided by my ISP. Additionally, I updated to Rails 7.0.3 and installed a new 'Let's Encrypt' SSL certificate.

Since then, whenever I try to send mail from the Rails app, the logs show the message 'Redirecting to https://mydomain' and nothing is sent. I have verified that I can send unauthenticated mail directly using `sendmail` and `mailx` and I can send authenticated mail via `msmtp` through `mail.mydomain`.

The fault must be with my app setup. Currently `production.rb` has the following mail settings.

```
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  # specify what domain to use for mailer URLs
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'mydomain', protocol: 'https' }
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: 'mail.mydomain',
    port: 465,
    domain: 'mydomain',
    user_name: <user>,
    password: <password>,
    authentication: 'plain',
    ssl: true,
    tls: true,
    open_timeout: 5,
    read_timeout: 5
  }
```

Outgoing mail is queued through Active Job using `good_job` as a background processor, but it is after `good_job` executes `#deliver_now` that `Redirected to https://mydomain` occurs.

I don't understand why it is Redirecting, or what to try next.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort out this problem eventually and thought I would post it FYI. Firstly, `msmtp` is a great program for testing your mail, but I had overlooked that installs its own MTA and changes the way `sendmail` operates in that it expects a configuration script in the effective user's home directory (by default `~/.msmtprc`). This meant that it wasn't using my config in `production.rb`. So I recovered the default behaviour by uninstalling `msmtp` and reinstalling `postfix`. Moral: Read The Manual!

Now that `ActionMailer` was reading my credentials again I noticed that mail sent via `#deliver_now` was sent, but mail queued for background delivery via `#deliver_later` was not. It turned out that an upgrade of `good_job` had caused it to default to an execution mode of `:external`. In this mode it waits for an external trigger, e.g. a `cron` job, to trigger processing – not what I needed. Resetting the execution mode to `:async` did the trick. Moral: as above.

Now my queued mail messages arrive as well.